# "Warning! PATH is not properly set up" when using RVM with virtualenv

Tags: ruby, rvm, virtualenv

I am getting this error:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.2'.
rvm 1.25.28 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

when I go inside any virtualenv. It takes the virtualenv's path at first place. In this example I called my virtualenv *borrar*, so this is my PATH:

```
/home/oscar/projects/borrar/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/oscar/eagle-6.6.0/bin:/home/oscar/android-studio/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

My path outside any virtualenv is which I assume is correct because **rvm is at first place**.:

```
/home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/oscar/eagle-6.6.0/bin:/home/oscar/android-studio/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/oscar/.rvm/bin
```

Here is my [.zshrc](https://gist.github.com/oskargicast/d8875e73c42ca1c449af)
and here my [.zsh_profile](https://gist.github.com/oskargicast/7437e3c71e432f28cc72) where I load RVM at the end.

I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### RVM Path Mismatch

RVM is complaining because it wants to be *first* in your PATH. It isn't; you've prepended something else, or your virtualenv wrappers have. This being the case, you can either reinvoke the RVM setup script from inside your virtualenv with `. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, or you can deliberately silence the error as described below.

The RVM documentation strongly recommends that the RVM setup script be the last thing you invoke in your shell resource files so that (among other things) RVM can be sure it takes precedence over other Rubies or wrappers that might be in your PATH. However, if you're *sure* that you know what you're doing and that you won't encounter any PATH-related surprises, you can turn off this warning by adding this little-known configuration option to your .rvmrc file:

```
echo 'rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1' >> ~/.rvmrc
```

Comment: This was helpful to me, because virtualenv also wants to be "first".  And I'm tired of hearing rvm complain